# How to filter intellisense errors from problems pane in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VSCode C++ extension often produces several 'problems' through its intellisense engine when viewing a file.  However, these are not often useful because the intellisense compiler is not the same compiler used in a C++ project (gcc, clang, etc)

Is there a way to optionally filter intellisense errors from the problems pane in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Try the extension's `errorSquiggles` setting:

```
"C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
```

> Controls whether suspected compile errors detected by the IntelliSense engine will be reported back to the editor. Warnings about #includes that could not be located will always be reported to the editor. This setting is ignored by the Tag Parser engine.